# browsers don't work(chrome err 137:name resolution failed), but everything is ok in gnome terminal

Tags: debian, browser

My system is debian 6.0. Both debian default brower and chrome don't work. The error is `name resolution failed(code:137)`. I can ping and update software in gnome terminal.

Yesterday I installed pptp-linux, and pptp did work, I also could surf internet by chrome.
Today I can't surf internet by browsers. after I remove pptp-linux, it still exist.

Have you encountered it?

Comment: Did you restart Chrome? On some systems, each program reads the DNS (name resolution) configuration when it starts, and doesn't see configuration changes after it's started. I don't know if this applies to a modern Linux system.

Comment: duplicate from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501381/browsers-dont-workchrome-err-137name-resolution-failed-but-everything-is-ok).

Comment: @Gilles Only Chrome 15 includes a built in DNS client and it must be enabled by flags.

Comment: You could try using Google's DNS?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. when executing the browers in root, I can surf internet. I don't know why.

Comment: lol, maybe some software has prevented you from doing something very stupid... browsing as root.

Comment: @xenoterracide♦ that's the exact opposite of what was posted.

Comment: If this still happens, can you try getting an `strace` of `chrome` (`strace chrome`) and look for the `open()` calls, then check the permissions and ownership of the called files. A possible explanation would be that some file `chrome` -- for some reason -- uses to resolve names is not available to anyone but `UID=0`.